# Extremely high String.equalsIgnoreCase CPU usage

Tags: java, jetty, java-17

I'm running a fairly large Spring Boot web application with Jetty as the container.
I have a filter that detects slow responses and logs some data about the request. This has been working very successfully for years but I have just added a check for whether the header name is "authorization" into the logging so that sensitive data is not logged in these cases and the whole CPU is used up on comparing strings. I have only on or two threads in this method and I don't see how this can be happening.

Old code with no problem:

```java
Enumeration<String> headers = request.getHeaderNames();
while (headers.hasMoreElements()) {
    String name = headers.nextElement();

    Enumeration<String> headerValues = request.getHeaders(name);
    while (headerValues.hasMoreElements()) {
        r.append(name);
        r.append(": ");
        r.append(headerValues.nextElement());
        r.append(System.lineSeparator());
    }
}
```

Problem code:

```java
Enumeration<String> headers = request.getHeaderNames();
while (headers.hasMoreElements()) {
    String name = headers.nextElement();

    Enumeration<String> headerValues = request.getHeaders(name);
    while (headerValues.hasMoreElements()) {
        if (!name.equalsIgnoreCase("authorization")) {
            r.append(name);
            r.append(": ");
            r.append(headerValues.nextElement());
            r.append(System.lineSeparator());
        }
    }
}
```

The time is spent in `java.lang.StringLatin1.regionMatchesCI` which should only be called for headers of length 13. In addition it seems that the time is spent in `java.lang.Character.toLowerCase`.

Total CPU for this application goes from around 10% to 98% with this change.

Comment: @user16320675 Good point, but probably should not matter here: it would be somewhat surprising to have more than one `Authorization` header, outside a DOS attack

Comment: The `toLowerCase` comparison is only done if comparing characters with `toUpperCase` has already failed to match, which makes think this is not a plain old comparison of "AUTHORIZATION" to "authorization" or something. Would be interesting to know what you're actually comparing it to. I'd log all 13-length strings and see what you're actually being given.

Comment: @user16320675 no, you misread the code. the `headerValues` enumerator only has 1 element in it. Hence, your suggestion makes no difference. Unless, as Amadan pointed out, someone is sending more than 1 Authorization: header.

Comment: @mjaggard Unless something is really trying to break this app in two and is sending ginormous header keys, what you say just cannot be. Or at least, is __extraordinary__. And, as the saying goes, therefore requires extraordinary evidence. How are you determining that most CPU resources are now spent on Character.toLowerCase?

Comment: @rzwitserloot fair question and something I overlooked but I can't see how it could be the cause of the issue. I have discovered that I have `-XX:+UseStringDeduplication` set but again I wouldn't expect that to matter here.

Comment: I've been looking at what could perform bytecode manipulation and found that I also have Elastic APM 1.16.0 included but `ELASTIC_APM_ENABLED` set to `false`. Aside from that it's only Spring as far as I can tell. I've also reverted that single line and confirmed that it fixes the issue on all environments.

Comment: The only two headers I can found that *were* logged are these:
cf-ipcountry
Content-Type
Sadly my load balancer access logs don't include headers.

Comment: The spec of HttpServletRequest (I assume that's the type of `request` here) includes the rule that it's case insensitive. So it's doing a case insensitive comparison of some form on everything, further highlighting how utterly bizarre this is. Go with a `.toLowerCase()` alternative, just to eliminate it. Does that 'fix' the problem, even if theoretically that should be slower (as it won't check size first)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251252/discussion-between-mjaggard-and-rzwitserloot).

Comment: OK. I am an idiot. Of course the second while loop never completes - I'm not calling `nextElement` and so `hasMoreElements` is always true  I'm so sorry to waste your time everyone. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @mjaggard Not an idiot. Easy one to miss actually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing basically doing toLowerCase in a loop against the same value over and over again because `hasMoreElements` will always be true if you don't call `nextElement`.

You could do it this way instead.

```java
Enumeration<String> headers = request.getHeaderNames();
while (headers.hasMoreElements()) {
    String name = headers.nextElement();

    if (!name.equalsIgnoreCase("authorization")) {
        Enumeration<String> headerValues = request.getHeaders(name);
        while (headerValues.hasMoreElements()) {
            r.append(name);
            r.append(": ");
            r.append(headerValues.nextElement());
            r.append(System.lineSeparator());
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. My locale is known and safe because I run my own server.
2. toLowercase is normally less performant because in equalsIgnoreCase the length is checked first among other reasons. 3. I don't have any duplicated headers in my request so moving the check won't (as far as I can tell) make any difference.

Comment: It's better to know the limits of the HTTP spec and use those limits to your benefit (example: header names and values can only contain 7-bit US-ASCII, and what's returned from the Servlet API is always constrained in that scope)

Comment: I'm using latin1 as my character set here and my server is in english locale so I think those should give the fastest performance for 7-bit ASCII. That being said this is not a "performance issue" as such - the CPU is being hammered for very few requests.

Comment: OK. I am an idiot. Of course the second while loop never completes - I'm not calling `nextElement` and so `hasMoreElements` is always true  I'm so sorry to waste your time everyone. Thanks for your help.